# Firebase Cloud Functions - get database list?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that looks like this:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/node/{id}').onDelete((snap, context) => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/aDifferentNode/${context.params.id}/someProperty`).set(false);
});
```

But now I am going to have multiple databases in my project. My understanding is that the above code will only work on the primary database instance, but I need it to apply to all of them in the same fashion. I don't want to hard-code the names of the databases I have because this same code will be deployed in multiple projects.

Is there a way to have `functions.database` operate across multiple databases and get the current database from the `context` or something along those lines? Or failing that, is there a way to get a list of all the databases in the project so I can create multiple functions programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API to list database shards that will work in Cloud Functions.  There is also no way to simply say that a function should respond to all instances.  You have to know all the names of the shards ahead of time, and [bake them into your deployed functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path).  What you *can* do is simply attach the same function to each of them, if they all have the same schema that require the same triggers.  But there is no avoiding registering a function for each shard.